# @Pattern not working on controller method with path variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created a controller with an update (PUT) request and applied regex on the id field as shown below but the pattern doesn't get executed and returning back SUCCESS instead of BAD_REQUEST.

```
@PutMapping("users/{id}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<UsersApiDTO>> update(@PathVariable @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z]{1,20}$") String id, @RequestBody @Valid UsersApiDTO usersApiDTO) {
    // return response
}
```

when I pass the wrong 'id' path field value "T001223242345" it is working. It should give me BAD_REQUEST as it works for the request body like if I pass any invalid value for the body parameter it gives BAD_REQUEST.

I have gone through many links and blogs but no luck yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the [@Validated annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) onto your `RestController` in order for path variables to get validated:

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class YourController {
    [...]
```

I would also suggest reviewing [Validating RequestParams and PathVariables in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-requestparam-pathvariable).

Comment: This answer no longer seems to work. Steps I took:
1. using SpringBoot 3.1.0 with spring-boot-starter-validation included in my build.gradle
2. added Spring's `@Validated` to my `@RestController` with the `@PostMapping` method I want to validate
3. added `@Pattern` to the `@PathVariable` method parameter.

No luck. The same method has `@Valid` on a separate `@RequestBody` parameter and all that validation works perfectly, but the `@Pattern` on the `@PathVariable` is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @Validated to your Controller class, and that should work. If it isn't please try to use the latest hibernate validator:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```